# How to seed data during deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

During deployment (to a shared host), I'd like check whether certain data is stored in the database, if not I'd like to insert it during the deployment process. Anyone know how to do what I've described?

Comment: Have you checked out Rails migrations guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: @Mladen Jablanovic: Yes, I've checked out the guide; the problem is I don't have ssh access, thus I can't run `rake` commands.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `rake db:seed`

There's even a railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

Comment: Problem is I don't have ssh access, thus I can't run `rake db:seed`

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use fixtures to populate my database, whether it's testing or not. Once you create them, you can just create a rake task to reset your db and populate it. I have this reset_db.rake task :

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Drop, create, migrate, seed the database and prepare the test database for rspec"
  task :reset_db => :environment do
    Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:create'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:fixtures:load'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].invoke
  end
end
```

in my /lib/tasks folder. I execute it with "rake db:reset_db".

Comment: That is a really bad idea to use fixtures outside of their intended purpose which is even debatable if they are useful there instead of Factories

Comment: Well, David Hannson, the Rails creator, seems to disagree. I do as well, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much flexibility you have with your host regarding other databases (Don't know if you can create another database just for these values), but you can place these data in xml documents and then have a script to insert these values if they don't exist.

Comment: When you have access to Rails and rake db:seed why would you ever do that?

Answer (score 0):

---**DB SEED APPROACH**---

There is a file called seed.rb in db directory (app_root/db/seeds.rb) where you can add seed data.  Commented out instructions are available in the file (copied below).

```
# This file should contain all the record creation needed to seed the database with its default values.
# The data can then be loaded with the rake db:seed (or created alongside the db with db:setup).
#
# Examples:
#
#   cities = City.create([{ name: 'Chicago' }, { name: 'Copenhagen' }])
#   Mayor.create(name: 'Emanuel', city: cities.first)
```

You can fill in with the records you want to add eg :

```
Users.create(
            :email=>"dummy", :pwd_hash=>"3x35zbb2...", 
            :pwd_salt=>'423x', :admin=>true
)
```

...and then run rake db:seed to add the records to your tables.

---**EDITING MIGRATION APPROACH**---

Simplest option (though db:seed is probably better) is to just run migration with seed data.  Just had to do this.  Needed a seed user with admin privileges because site has no sign up option.  Migration file below:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.string :name
      t.boolean :admin
      t.integer :company_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    #create the seed user with admin priviledges
    User.create!(:email=>"dummy@dummy.com", :password=>"test", :name=>"Dummy", :admin=>true, :company_id=>0)

  end
end
```